# How to find height of status bar in Android through React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, statusbar

How can I find the height of the status bar on Android through React Native?

If I check the `React.Dimensions` height the value seems to include the status bar height too but I'm trying to find the height of the layout without the status bar.

Answer (score 151):

You don't need any plugins for this (anymore), just use `StatusBar.currentHeight`:

```
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';
console.log('statusBarHeight: ', StatusBar.currentHeight);
```

EDIT: Apparently this does seem to work on Android always, but on iOS, initially `undefined` is indeed returned :(

Comment: I got undefined returned

Comment: For me StatusBar.currentHeight does not work (undefined) on iOS on React Native 0.39.2.

Comment: RN@0.42 not working on iOS、haven't tested on Android yet

Comment: as per the doc it will currently(0.49) work only for android

Comment: RN v0.64: still only available on Android.

Answer (score 41):

Unfortunately, as of v0.34, the API to do this is still inconsistent across platforms. `StatusBarManager.HEIGHT` will give you the **current height** of the Status Bar on Android.

```
import { Platform, NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { StatusBarManager } = NativeModules;

const STATUSBAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : StatusBarManager.HEIGHT;
```

On iOS, you can use `getHeight()`

```
StatusBarManager.getHeight((statusBarHeight)=>{
  console.log(statusBarHeight)
})
```

As a side note, if you want your app to draw under the status bar on Android similar to the default iOS behavior, you can do so by setting a couple props on `<StatusBar>` as follows:

```
<StatusBar translucent={true} backgroundColor={'transparent'} {...props} />
```

Comment: IOS have always 20 in status bar height??

Comment: @DanielJosePadillaPeña Yes. Unless it's hidden, or an app is active during an incoming call—in which case it's 40 points.

Comment: @DanielJosePadillaPeña iOS X is different.

Comment: A better solution would be using  <SafeAreaView > which currently only supported for android. Then use this conditional statement for padding in your styles with the help of  StatusBar from reactNative  paddingTop:Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0

Comment: Using the components that you are importing caused phone lags on IOS 15, be careful

Answer (score 22):

You can use this helper function which enables you to get the Status Bar height on iOS and Android. For iOS, the calculation is done to get the different StatusBar height when >= iPhone X (with notch) is used.

```
// functions-file.js
import { Dimensions, Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const X_WIDTH = 375;
const X_HEIGHT = 812;

const XSMAX_WIDTH = 414;
const XSMAX_HEIGHT = 896;

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export const isIPhoneX = () => Platform.OS === 'ios' && !Platform.isPad && !Platform.isTVOS
    ? width === X_WIDTH && height === X_HEIGHT || width === XSMAX_WIDTH && height === XSMAX_HEIGHT
    : false;

export const StatusBarHeight = Platform.select({
    ios: isIPhoneX() ? 44 : 20,
    android: StatusBar.currentHeight,
    default: 0
})
```

Then use it directly when imported:

```
import { StatusBarHeight } from './functions-file.js'

height: StatusBarHeight
```

Another option if you use `react-navigation-stack` - it provides the header height via hook - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headertransparent

```
import { useHeaderHeight } from 'react-navigation-stack';

// ...

const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
```

Comment: This is out of data since it doesn't include newer iPhones. Looks like the package `react-native-status-bar-height` is a more up-to-date implementation of this method.

Answer (score 9):

import **Constants** and **Dimensions**.

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Dimensions  from 'react-native';
```

in stylesheet **container hight - status bar hight = without status hight**.

```
 container: {   height: Dimensions.get('window').height - Constants.statusBarHeight,}
```

Comment: And what if you're not using Expo?

Comment: @6rchid `expo-constants` can be installed in a bare (not expo managed) project. So @Oman answer is applicable in any case.

Comment: This solution is only easily useable at Expo managed workflow. This should be mentioned on top of this answer. Because the question is not asking anything directly for expo.

Answer (score 6):

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

// ...

const {StatusBarManager} = NativeModules;

const height = StatusBarManager.HEIGHT;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the height of the statusbar via

```
  import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'

  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets()

  console.log('height of status bar', insets.top)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `@react-navigation/native-stack`

```
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements';
const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
```

[Link to source](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#useheaderheight)

Answer (score 0):

For the situation where I need to escape a StatusBar component, my solution for Android is to use `StatusBar.currentHeight` to escape the StatusBar component. For
iOS I use react-native's `SafeAreaView` component to escape the StatusBar.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import {
  StatusBar,
  Platform,
  NativeModules,
} from 'react-native';
const {StatusBarManager} = NativeModules;

function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        ...
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors._primaryStatusBarBackgroundColor,
    paddingTop: Platform.OS ? StatusBarManager.HEIGHT : StatusBar.currentHeight, // it's worked for me 
  },
});
```

Instead of using SafeAreaView, I made this to work on every operating system

Answer (score -1):

The package [react-native-status-bar-height](https://github.com/ovr/react-native-status-bar-height) works well, however, if you don't want another dependency, I have extracted the gist here:

**Create file getStatusBarHeight.tsx**

```
import {Dimensions, Platform, StatusBar} from 'react-native';

const STATUSBAR_DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 20;
const STATUSBAR_X_HEIGHT = 44;
const STATUSBAR_IP12_HEIGHT = 47;
const STATUSBAR_IP12MAX_HEIGHT = 47;
const STATUSBAR_IP14PRO_HEIGHT = 49;

const X_WIDTH = 375;
const X_HEIGHT = 812;

const XSMAX_WIDTH = 414;
const XSMAX_HEIGHT = 896;

const IP12_WIDTH = 390;
const IP12_HEIGHT = 844;

const IP12MAX_WIDTH = 428;
const IP12MAX_HEIGHT = 926;

const IP14PRO_WIDTH = 393;
const IP14PRO_HEIGHT = 852;

const IP14PROMAX_WIDTH = 430;
const IP14PROMAX_HEIGHT = 932;

const {height: W_HEIGHT, width: W_WIDTH} = Dimensions.get('window');

let statusBarHeight = STATUSBAR_DEFAULT_HEIGHT;

if (Platform.OS === 'ios' && !Platform.isPad && !Platform.isTVOS) {
  if (W_WIDTH === X_WIDTH && W_HEIGHT === X_HEIGHT) {
    statusBarHeight = STATUSBAR_X_HEIGHT;
  } else if (W_WIDTH === XSMAX_WIDTH && W_HEIGHT === XSMAX_HEIGHT) {
    statusBarHeight = STATUSBAR_X_HEIGHT;
  } else if (W_WIDTH === IP12_WIDTH && W_HEIGHT === IP12_HEIGHT) {
    statusBarHeight = STATUSBAR_IP12_HEIGHT;
  } else if (W_WIDTH === IP12MAX_WIDTH && W_HEIGHT === IP12MAX_HEIGHT) {
    statusBarHeight = STATUSBAR_IP12MAX_HEIGHT;
  } else if (W_WIDTH === IP14PROMAX_WIDTH && W_HEIGHT === IP14PROMAX_HEIGHT) {
    statusBarHeight = STATUSBAR_IP14PRO_HEIGHT;
  } else if (W_WIDTH === IP14PRO_WIDTH && W_HEIGHT === IP14PRO_HEIGHT) {
    statusBarHeight = STATUSBAR_IP14PRO_HEIGHT;
  }
}

export function getStatusBarHeight() {
  return Platform.select({
    ios: statusBarHeight,
    android: StatusBar.currentHeight,
    default: 0,
  });
}
```

**Usage:**

```
import {getStatusBarHeight} from './getStatusBarHeight';

export const Test = () => {

  const statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight();

  return <Text style={{ marginTop: statusBarHeight }}>Test</Text>

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
deviceHeight={deviceHeight}
```