# Set paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight trought StatusBar Component, without expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, statusbar

With expo I can `import { Constants } from 'expo';` and set in styles `paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight`.

But we have `<StatusBar />` Component in React Native.

I want to know is there some way to do that with React Natives `<StatusBar />` Component's **props** not from **style** like in expo.

**Edit:** I don't want to get the status bar height. I want to know is there more better way to set my main `View`-s top padding as status bar height.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Do you want an effect like expo in react native?

Comment: You want to know the height of the StatusBar?

Comment: I want to know is there some props or other native mathods that I can use in `<StatusBar />` Component, something like this: <StatusBar upToHeader={true} /> . Or something like the difference beetwen `<KeyboardAvoidedView />` and `<View />`. I don't know how can I explain more :D  Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find height of status bar in Android through React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436643/how-to-find-height-of-status-bar-in-android-through-react-native)

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-statusbar/   <= about statusbar