# how get the current height of a header with `headerLargeTitle` set from `react-navigation/native-stack`

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

There is a way to get the current header height from `react-navigation/native-stack` with `headerLargeTitle` set? I've tried with [useHeaderHeight](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#useheaderheight) from `react-navigation/elements` but this always returns **64**, looks like is the [height from default headers + status bar height](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/elements/src/Header/getDefaultHeaderHeight.tsx#L38).

### Update 1: Reference

#### Header with large title

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? `height = NavBarHeight - StatusBarHeight`  or only `StatusBarHeight`? To get `StatusBarHeight` you can use `StatusBar.currentHeight`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436643/how-to-find-height-of-status-bar-in-android-through-react-native

Comment: I want to get the header height with `headerLargeTtile` set... I update my question with a reference of a header with large title